# Binary search tree deletion function in Python

Tags: python, binary-tree

I'm beginner in Python and I tried to create a function to delete a node in a binary search tree.

I tried calling `.delete` on a node. The node is a leaf node with no children so it should be deleted. However, after I called `.delete`, the node is still there.

This is the code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,key): 
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key 

    #some functions for insert etc.

    def delete(self, key):
        """DELETE"""
        try:
            if self is None:
                print("Tree is empty.")
                return None
            else:
                if key < self.val: 
                    self.left.delete(key) 

                elif key > self.val: 
                    self.right.delete(key)

                else: 
                    #this seems to be the problem
                    if self.left is None : 
                        temp = self.right
                        #print(self, self.val, self.right)
                        self = temp
                        return

                    elif self.right is None : 
                        temp = self.left  
                        self = temp
                        return  

                    temp = minValue(self.right)  
                    self.val = temp.val 

                    self.right.delete(temp.val) 
        except(AttributeError):
            print("There's no such number in a tree.")


def inorder(root):
    if root is not None: 
        inorder(root.left) 
        print(root.val, end=" ") 
        inorder(root.right) 


def minValue(node): 
    current = node  
    while(current.left is not None): 
        current = current.left    
    return current

r = Node(50)
```

After inserting numbers `30 20 40 70 60 80` to `r` and calling `inorder(r)` I get: `20 30 40 50 60 70 80`, which corresponds to the tree

```
      50 
    /    \ 
   30     70 
  /  \   /  \ 
 20  40 60  80
```

but after `r.delete(30)`, I get: `20 40 40 50 60 70 80`, which is:

```
      50 
    /    \ 
   40     70 
  /  \   /  \ 
 20  40 60  80
```

The value to delete is replaced correctly but the used node (`40`) without children should be deleted.

What may be the reason of such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you cannot assign anything to `self`. In Python, `self` is a reference to the object that you called the method on. It would not be `None` (so you don't need the `if self is None` check), and you cannot assign some other value to it.

However, when deleting a node from the tree, it is possible that the current node (the node which you called `delete` on) will be deleted. Instead of assigning values to `self`, we can make the `delete` return a node object. If the current node is not deleted, simply return itself; otherwise, return the node the will take its place (or `None` if the entire subtree is gone).

Here's the modified implementation, along with an `insert` method and a test case:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.left = self.right = None
        self.val = key

    def delete(self, key):
        """Delete a node with value `key`."""
        if key < self.val: 
            # Find and delete the value in the left subtree.
            if self.left is None:
                # There's no left subtree; the value does not exist.
                raise ValueError("Value not found in tree")
            self.left = self.left.delete(key)
            return self  # current node not deleted, just return
        elif key > self.val: 
            # Find and delete the value in the right subtree.
            if self.right is None:
                # There's no right subtree; the value does not exist.
                raise ValueError("Value not found in tree")
            self.right = self.right.delete(key)
            return self  # current node not deleted, just return
        else:
            # The current node should be deleted.
            if self.left is None and self.right is None:
                # The node has no children -- it is a leaf node. Just delete.
                return None

            # If the node has only one children, simply return that child.
            if self.left is None:
                return self.right
            if self.right is None:
                return self.left

            # The node has both left and right subtrees, and they should be merged.
            # Following your implementation, we find the rightmost node in the
            # left subtree and replace the current node with it.
            parent, node = self, self.left
            while node.right is not None:
                parent, node = node, node.right
            # Now, `node` is the rightmost node in the left subtree, and
            # `parent` its parent node. Instead of replacing `self`, we change
            # its attributes to match the value of `node`.
            if parent.left is node:
                # This check is necessary, because if the left subtree has only
                # node, `node` would be `self.left`.
                parent.left = None
            else:
                parent.right = None
            self.val = node.val
            return self

    def insert(self, key):
        if key < self.val:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(key)
            else:
                self.left.insert(key)
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(key)
            else:
                self.right.insert(key)

def inorder_traverse(node):
    if node is None:
        return []
    ret = []
    if node.left is not None:
        ret += inorder_traverse(node.left)
    ret.append(node.val)
    if node.right is not None:
        ret += inorder_traverse(node.right)
    return ret

values = [5, 1, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4]
root = Node(values[0])
for x in values[1:]:
    root.insert(x)
print(inorder_traverse(root))

for x in values:
    root = root.delete(x)
    print(inorder_traverse(root))
```

The output is, as expected:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 6]
[4, 6]
[4]
[]
```